# Phoenix Varnish Cache: ESI Tag Not Remove

Tags: magento, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am install Varnish Cache 4.3 on linux ngnix server and PageCache powered by Varnish Module in Magento.
this is my /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "80";
}
```

this is my /etc/varnish/default.vcl_3.0

```
include "vars.vcl";
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "6081";
}
backend admin {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "6081";
  .first_byte_timeout = 18000s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 18000s;
}
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}
# purge request
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    ban("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Host + " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Regex + " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
    error 200 "Purged.";
}
```

This is my DAEMON_OPTS is

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
             -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
             -w ${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS},${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS},${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
             -p esi_syntax=0*03 \
             -p shm_reclen=4096 \
             -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
```

And My Module setting in Magento Admin

```
Varnish servers  :  127.0.0.1;192.168.1.19
Server port       : 6081
```

***My Problem is esi tag come in where form_key comes***

```
esi:include src='http://mydesk:6081/varnishcache/getformkey/ this come in form
```

Please see my configuration file and Please Suggest me where i am going wrong  or Suggest me full process How Varnish is install?.....

**Thanks is Advance........**